# How do I change order of parameter in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I'm working on `SSRS reports` and unable to change order of parameter which is coming into dropdown list please help me

```
=First(Fields!PortfolioName.Value, "PortfolioName") & " : " & Switch
    (
     Parameters!SourceID.Value = 13,
     "Official",
     Parameters!SourceID.Value = Nothing,
     "Internal" ,
     Parameters!SourceID.Value = 15,
     "Broker Dealer"
     ) & " Pricing"
```

gives `id` and `porfolioname`

for better understanding i paste a image here.

I want default value to be `official` at top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the Pricing Source info is available in another table called "PricingSource".

(1) Use the following query to fetch pricing info data :

```
SELECT PricingSourceID, PricingSourceName
    FROM PricingSource
    WHERE PricingSourceId
ORDER BY CASE PricingSourceName
WHEN 'Official' THEN 1
ELSE 999
END
```

(2) Now use this query in another dataset and utilize this dataset in "Available Values" for the parameter "Pricing Source" in the SSRS to populate the dropdown list

---

Comment: hi thanks for reply .. in my `princing source` dropdown 3 values are there `Internal` , 'Official' ,'Broker Dealer'
now when I execute report value `Internal` is at 1st position as we see in image but I want `Official` as 1st position for this I made change like shown in post make that `Official` item before `Internal` but its not working  plz help

Comment: i have tried the given query and it works with AdventureWorks database... if it doesn't work for you , may be you need to elaborate on your problem a little more.